VIM auto fill path without expanding the variable
Is there any way to auto fill path without expanding the variable?
for example, if i want to complete the path:
$PATH/src/complete/
using ctrl-x ctrl-f while in insert mode also expand the variable and i would like to keep it.

Yes, create a directory named $PATH. But, seriously no. The whole point of :help i_ctrl-x_ctrl-f is to return a real file path and $PATH/src/complete/ is not. You would have to write your own completion function for that.

https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2620 - Don't expand environment variable in filename_complete. (Among many other features).
